# Disable no-use-before-declare

Tags: javascript, typescript

I can't figure out how to disable this in my `tsconfig` file. I don't see a prop for that in the TS docs for `tsconfig`

[no-use-before-declare](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-use-before-declare/)
I need to do this because my test stub data objects are tripping each other in a certain situation and moving them around doesn't make a difference.

[image]

And if I move countryStub up then I get:

[image]

likewise if I move locationStub up, I get:

[image]

And if I move communityStub up I get:

[image]

since only tests are using this, I could care less about this error so I want to disable it.

Comment: is countryStub being declared in the same file but lower down? I think it really is invalid to be using that value where you are - Does this code throw an error when its run?

Comment: same file... these are all in the same file.

Comment: Why do you think it's invalid the way I'm using it?  If I move countryStub up, the problem is, then I get the same error happening on communityStub.  So no matter how I re-arrange those 3 above, I keep getting this error on certain props

Comment: If I put the following into a file in node and run it, I get an error: `const a = {...b}; const b = {x:2}`. From what I understand, your code is basically doing that ...

Comment: there are different use cases for these stubs depending on how different tests use these stubs, so I need to disable this strict checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have going on is a circular relationship. The way you have it coded above will likely cause a runtime error - so this isn't just your linter warning you about a bad code practice, its telling you there's a real bug in your code that will effect your tests. because you're trying to use a value before its defined. Here's how you can create a circular relationship without such an error:

```
const a = {}
const b = { a }
const c = { b }
a.c = c // Note how we have to attach c to a after c is defined
```

This is not a *real* answer - I don't know how to disable that rule, so hopefully someone else can come along and answer that here. But this should help your specific issue.

**EDIT**

Here is a working example of your code. When I copied it over, it was indeed throwing the error the linter was warning about, but with some tweaks it was working again.

```
export const locationStub = {
  name: ''
}

export const communityStub = {
  countryId: 0,
  name: ''
}

export const countryStub = {
  countryId: 0,
  name: '',
  communities: [{...communityStub}]
}

// copy countryStub *after* its defined
locationStub.country = {...countryStub}

// NOTE: communityStub was copying itself into itself - not sure what you were wanting here.
// There's a couple ways to get a similar effect.
// What I did below kept the copying behavior.
// This will result in the following shape:
//   { countryId: 0, communities: [{ contryId: 0 }] }
// If you prefer, we can ditch the copying and make an infinite self-relationship.
// e.g. communityStub.communities = [communityStub]
communityStub.communities = [{...communityStub}]
```

Comment: there is no runtime error, they will be used from tests.  And the spread operator is creating copies of each anyway.

Comment: Oh, maybe I'm not being clear with "runtime error". I'm not talking about just when your application is running, but also when your tests are running. Both of those are runtime. That code you posted shouldn't be able to execute as it stands, so tests trying to import that module should fail.

Comment: If you do `node nameOfThisStubModule.js`, does it throw an error, or does nothing happen?

Comment: yea so what I ended up doing is just keeping the props first level and putting nulls for the location and country fields in the stub. Then just set them with the spread operator from the tests to get around this problem

Comment: Glad you found a solution :). I did edit my answer with another possible solution you could try if you want.

Comment: yea looks like you kinda did what I ended up doing from my tests but just you did it from within the stub file.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just setting some of the fields to null and setting them from my tests with stubs instead:

```js
export const communityStub: Community = {
  communityId: 0,
  imageUrl: '',
  name: '',
  location: null
};

export const countryStub: Country = {
  countryId: 0,
  name: '',
  communities: [{...communityStub}]
}

export const locationStub: Location = {
  name: '',
  country: null
}
```

e.g. from a test

```
const countries = [{...countryStub}, {...countryStub}];
  countries[0].communities = [{...communityStub}];
  countries[0].countryId = 0;
  countries[0].communities[0].location = {...locationStub};
  countries[0].communities[0].location.country = {...countryStub};
```